# React navigation stack navigator working with draw navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, react-navigation

I want to make a simple application with stackNavigator and DrawerNavigator (react native).
The application will have a login and a welcome page, I would like it in the login: drawerNavigator does not work and in the welcome page if it works.
The tree would be something like:

**StackNavigator:**

- Login
- Register

**DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator:**

- Welcome Page
- My Profile

This is my code, what is not good is to show the drawerNavigator in all sections.

```
const PreLogin = StackNavigator(
{
  Login:{
    screen: listView,
    mode:'modal',
       navigationOptions:{
    title: 'Login',

   }
 },
    Register: { 
    screen: Register,
     navigationOptions:{
    title: 'Registro'
   }
 },
   Profile: {
    screen: ListScreenTwo
  }
}

);

const Draw = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: PreLogin,
  },
   Profile: {
    screen: ListScreenTwo
  }

});





AppRegistry.registerComponent('eatq', () => Draw);
```

Sorry for my terrible English, i love your language.